# Can the Trader destroy a disease card?

Tags: thunderstone-dragonspire

The trader card says:

> **Village**: In addition to your by, you may destroy 1 card to take any non-Hero card worth up to 2 cost more from the village.

Disease doesn't have a cost listed, so even if it can be destroyed it is somewhat ambiguous as to what you could acquire afterwards.  Does anyone know how this should be played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The publisher's representative (Ryan Metzler) states in this thread that trashing a disease with a trader is an illegal move:
http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/622651/village-trader-question

The rest of it sort of falls apart because he missed that they were erroneously talking about gold values, not cost, but it's the closest thing to an official answer I could find that you can't trash a card with no-cost to the Trader.

Also, clearly stated here:
http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/7763776#7763776

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen (though not an official ruling) is that cards with no cost printed on them are assumed to have a cost of 0, and so can be destroyed to get something that costs up to 2. Note that these are costs, not gold values (so the amount of gold you have to pay to get the card in your deck, not the amount of gold the card gives you when it's in your hand and you go to the village).

This is different than my understanding of gold value where I think that something needs to be printed on the card (why else would the Militia cards have a printed 0 gold value? why not just leave the gold value off?) I'm less certain on my interpretations of gold value though, so could be interpreting things incorrectly.